# .NET Core - Multiple read/write operations on a text file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.2

Multiple read/write operation are access a single file, and while write operation I'm facing this issue

`The process cannot access the file because it is being used in another process`

Using this to add text to file

```
using (StreamWriter writer=System.IO.File.AppendText("wwwroot/Files/file.txt"))
      {
           writer.WriteLine(stringData.ToString());
           writer.Close();
      }
```

Is there anyway to perform multiple read/write on a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If are using the same code from multiple threads or apps writing to the same file, you may find when one thread is wiring it finds the file already in use.
The only reason for the error message is that the file is not closed.

If the calls to write to the file are sequential from the same app then the file is not getting closed properly.

One way to handle this is to check for locked files and retry later.
something like this can be used to check if the file is open:

```
public static bool CanBeOpenedForExclusiveRead(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                // Test file for exclusive read/write
                using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    fileStream.Close();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            return false;
        }
```

if you are already using something like NLog is to use nlog to "log" writes to a file, where nlog will have better handling of these issues across threads.

Comment: I'm also trying to add/create custom middleware logging for request, response and header info and save those info in a text file. But as many function will try to access the same file this will create issue while reading the file. And for viewing I'm serving that text file placed in wwwroot.

Comment: reading the file shouldn't be an issue. a logging mechanism to a specific file might work better than doing it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. You may not need a StreamWriter for this

```
        // To append text to file
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("FilePath", "TextToWrite");

        // To read all text from file
        string textFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("FilePath");
```

Comment: There is no practical difference between code here and what OP posted (as `AppendAllText` does roughly the same what OP already has)... Clearly, they did not show part where reads are happening in parallel to write, but that seem to be given based on the tags. Some explanation why you believe your code resolves all possible issues would be helpful.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov actually I'm tring to replicate what logging does, adding info related to function request, response and header info with timestamp. But for only certain listing of function ( around 15-17 ), and in read function I'm just accessing/serving that text file which I've placed in my wwwroot folder ( /logs/mylogs.txt ) in my browser